# Process Monitor (Procmon) path of \\.\.\

Tags: procmon

I'm working through a procmon capturing trying to analyze a problem, and I Have about forty lines that look like this:

```
0.700867755 Explorer.EXE    10480   CreateFile  \\.\.\  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened   \\.\.\
0.700867755 Explorer.EXE    10480   FileSystemControl   \\.\.\  SUCCESS Control: CSC_FSCTL_OPERATION_QUERY_HANDLE   \\.\.\
0.700867755 Explorer.EXE    10480   FileSystemControl   \\.\.\  SUCCESS Control: CSC_FSCTL_OPERATION_QUERY_HANDLE   \\.\.\
0.700867755 Explorer.EXE    10480   CloseFile   \\.\.\  SUCCESS     \\.\.\
0.700867766 Explorer.EXE    10480   CreateFile  \\.\.\  SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Directory, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened   \\.\.\
0.700867766 Explorer.EXE    10480   FileSystemControl   \\.\.\  SUCCESS Control: CSC_FSCTL_OPERATION_QUERY_HANDLE   \\.\.\
0.700867766 Explorer.EXE    10480   FileSystemControl   \\.\.\  SUCCESS Control: CSC_FSCTL_OPERATION_QUERY_HANDLE   \\.\.\
0.700867766 Explorer.EXE    10480   CloseFile   \\.\.\  SUCCESS     \\.\.\
```

What does `\\.\.\` denote for the path? It looks like a relative path, but I've never seen a relative path before in a Procmon output.

Comment: its a UNC path, so `\\.` means localhost, and `\.\` means the root dir for the filesystem.  in linux and windows `.` means "current" whether its the machine or the directory. likewise `..` means the parent.